# Setting fullscreen mode is leaving dead space in bottom of android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on what should be a full-screen application but when I set my app full-screen I noticed a dead space in the bottom. Like if the app had a bottom margin I can't seem to get rid of that. 
I have tried from

```
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

and I have also tried programmatically like this

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

This last segment of code I wrote before setContentView, just to clear that out. 
But nothing seems to work. I really don't know what the problem is but I would really appreciate some pointers.

Comment: maybe the content doesn't take up full screen space

Comment: Well it should really. And in the xml file it is set to fill_parent. So I dont understand why it isnt stretching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something related to target SDK in your manifest, try playing with it by setting it to 14 and to 4

**Edit**

Try

```
WebView view = new WebView(this);
view.setSystemUiVisibility(WebView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Comment: What is the device you are testing on?

Comment: @JulioC What is the device you are testing on?

Comment: I am testing it on galaxy s3.

Comment: That actually really helped. Thanks. Appreciate the help! Problem solved!